# flatten a map to a list in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have this map:

```
  mymap = "${
      map(
      "key1", "111111",
      "key2", "222222",
      "key3", "333333"
      )
  }"
```

I need it as a map for some things but for other things I just need a list of values like this:

```
mymap = [
  "111111","222222","333333"
]
```

How can I convert the map to a list and store in another variable (in locals)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html) function something you're looking for?

Using `0.12` syntax for clarity:

```
locals {
  myvalues = values(local.mymap)
}
```

Comment: hell yes. exactly what I wanted